# Facebook SDK App Invitation

Tags: ios, facebook

When im using facebook sdk invitation ,the FBSDKAppInviteDialogDelegate method (-(void)appInviteDialog:(FBSDKAppInviteDialog *)appInviteDialog didFailWithError:(NSError *)error) returns :

"error =  Error Domain=com.facebook.sdk.core Code=2 "(null)" UserInfo={com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorDeveloperMessageKey=Invalid method_results., com.facebook.sdk:FBSDKErrorArgumentNameKey=method_results}"